# Existence of a group isomorphism between $(\mathbb K,+)$ and $(\mathbb K^\times,\cdot)$

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

> Let $(\mathbb K,+,\cdot)$ be a field.
>
> Is there a group isomorphism between $(\mathbb K,+)$ and $(\mathbb K^\times,\cdot) $ ?

The answer should clearly be negative.

I tried to proceed via contradiction, but this has not led me very far.

Since it's some kind of "trick problem", I'm merely looking for hints.

Comment: But what about a finite field, $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$?

Comment: If you think the answer is clearly negative, you should be trying to exhibit a counterexample, not trying to use contradiction.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm saying there's no such isomorphism.

Comment: You haven't specified a quantifier on the field. Is the question whether there *ever* exists such an isomorphism, or whether there *always* exists such an isomorphism? If the latter, you just need to exhibit a single field for which such an isomorphism doesn't exist (a finite field will do).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I thought I had made that explicit. Let me rephrase: Given an arbitrary field $\mathbb K$,  is there a group isomorphism between $(\mathbb K,+)$ and $(\mathbb K^\times,\cdot) $ ?

Comment: That still doesn't specify the quantifier. Do you want to know whether there *always* exists such an isomorphism or whether there *ever* exists such an isomorphism? Again, the answer to the first question is straightforwardly no, and the proof is you exhibit a single counterexample.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan "ever" is what I'm looking for. The "always" case follows from a cardinality argument.

Comment: Can you explain why 'the additive and multiplicative groups have different cardinalities'? Thanks

Comment: @MarcGato this is trivially true in a finite field, but wrong if $\mathbb K = \mathbb R$ for example.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is never such an isomorphism. For finite fields this is straightforward because the additive and multiplicative groups have different cardinalities. For infinite fields we can proceed as follows:

If the field $k$ does not have characteristic $2$, then $-1$ is an element of order $2$ in $k^{\times}$. But by hypothesis, since $k$ does not have characteristic $2$, the additive group of $k$ is a vector space over the prime subfield of $k$, which is not $\mathbb{F}_2$, so it has no elements of order $2$. Hence it cannot be isomorphic to the multiplicative group. If $k$ has characteristic $2$, then the additive group of $k$ contains only elements of order $2$. On the other hand, $k$ is infinite, but the equation $x^2 = 1$ admits at most two solutions in a field, so again the additive group cannot be isomorphic to the multiplicative group.

Comment: Excellent answer! One might wonder what this would be if the field is relaxed to a unitary ring.