# To prove that $(F,+)$ and $(F-\{0\},\cdot)$ are not isomorphic as groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $(F,+,\cdot)$ be a field.

Then to prove that $(F,+)$ and $(F-\{0\},\cdot)$ are not isomorphic as groups.

I am facing difficulty in finding the map to bring a contradiction!!

Comment: You should already know this by now, but in order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: If the idea is to show that no such map exists, then trying to _find_ the map isn't going to work. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I don't think imperative verbs (prove this, solve that, find this, etc.) in this context are rude, but they are usually inappropriate, for a different reason.  The reason is that one is supposed to ask a question here. The use of the imperative grammatical mood can lead to a suspicion that the poster is doing stenography and not understanding the words he's typing and doesn't actually have a question in mind. In the case of this particular question, I don't suspect that and I will not vote to close it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080499/existence-of-a-group-isomorphism-between-mathbb-k-and-mathbb-k-times

Answer (score 8):

Show:

- if the additive group contains an element of order $2$ then the multiplicative does not.
- if the additive group contains no element of order $2$ then the multiplicative does.

Answer (score 6):

Quid's answer is in one sense the same as what I was about to post when I read it.  But the way I phrased it may make it clear to some people first learning the subject, in a way that quid's might not.

Suppose an isomorphism $\varphi$ from the multiplicative group to the additive group exists.  In a field in which $-1\ne1$, we have $(-1)^2=1$ and so $\varphi(-1)+\varphi(-1)=\varphi(1)=0$.  This is a field in which $2\ne0$, so it is permissible to divide both sides of the equality $2\varphi(-1)=0$ by $2$ and get $\varphi(-1)=0$.  That puts $-1$ in the kernel of the homomorphism $\varphi$, which, being an isomorphism, should have only $1$ in its kernel.

In a field in which $-1=1$ one uses a different argument.