# Prove that The additive group (K;+) and the multiplicative group (K; . ) of a field K are never isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This question is from an assignment I am trying to solve in abstract algebra.

> Prove that The additive group (K;+) and the multiplicative group (K; . ) of a field K are never
> isomorphic.

Let on the converse they are isomorphic and f is an isomorphism then f(0)=1.but I am unable to find any contradiction and need help.

Comment: Use the distributive law

Comment: How many self-inverse elements do either group have?

Comment: In case when Char K not 2 , this proof by michael hardy is easy to understand:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179497/to-prove-that-f-and-f-0-cdot-are-not-isomorphic-as-groups?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Consider the equation $x^2 = 1.$ What can you say about solutions to this equation in $K^\times$? What is the corresponding equation in $(K,+),$ and what can you say about solutions to this in $K$?

**Subhint:** You may want to consider the cases $\operatorname{char}(K) = 2$ and $\operatorname{char}(K)\neq 2$ separately.

Comment: Can you please tell in this answer :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080499/existence-of-a-group-isomorphism-between-mathbb-k-and-mathbb-k-times . Why the Additive and Multiplicative group have different cardinalities in finite field case in the answer of user quicho yuan

Comment: @James The additive group of a field consists of all the elements in the field. The multiplicative group of a field consists of all the non-zero elements in the field. If $K$ is a finite field with $n$ elements, then the additive group will have $n$ elements, and the multiplicative group will have $n - 1$ elements.

Comment: Consider the answer of user Quicho Yuan :  "If k has characteristic 2, then the additive group of k contains only elements of order 2. On the other hand, k is infinite, but the equation $x^2=1$ admits at most two solutions in a field, so again the additive group cannot be isomorphic to the multiplicative group."

Comment: ( Yuan is not active for a lot of months, that's why I am asking you. I will accept your answer)It is never written that k is infinite. If Char K =2 then Additive group will admit only 1 solution of equation $x^2 =1$ which will be 1 not two and how does this implies that additive group is not isomorphic  to multiplicative group.

Comment: @James Let $G$ be any group, and consider the subset $$T(G) = \{g\in G\mid g^2 = e_G\}.$$ A group isomorphism $f : G\to G'$ will send $T(G)$ to $T(G')$ bijectively. To see this, suppose that $g\in T(G).$ Then $g^2 = e_G,$ and applying $f$ to both sides of this equation gives $$f(g)^2 = f(g^2) = f(e_G) = e_{G'}.$$ Thus, $g\in T(G)$ implies $f(g)\in T(G').$ The inverse of $f$ will similarly send $T(G')$ to $T(G),$ so that the two are in bijection via $f$ and its inverse.

Comment: We can consider the set above when $G = (k,+)$ and $G' = (k^\times, \cdot).$ If $\operatorname{char}k = 2,$ $2x = 0$ for every $x\in k,$ so that $T(k,+) = k.$ However, the equation $x^2 = 1$ has only one solution in a field of characteristic 2: $1.$ Thus, $$T(k,^\times,\cdot) = \{x\in k^\times\mid x^2 = 1\} = \{1\}.$$ So, $\# T(k,+) = \# k > 1,$ as a field must have more than one element, but $\#T(k^\times,\cdot) = 1,$ so the two cannot be in bijection. A group isomorphism $f : (k,+)\to (k^\times,\cdot)$ would induce a bijection between these sets. Therefore, such an isomorphism cannot exist.